# Objective-c enum class

Tags: objective-c, class, enums

I'm trying to create a enumeration class in objective-c. Here below is what I already got.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

typedef enum  {
    Car,
    Bike,
    Boat
} Vehicle;

@interface ModelVehicle : NSObject {

    Vehicle vehicle;

}

@property (nonatomic) Vehicle vehicle;

@end
```

Now I can access the enum from another class but only with the following code. Why can't I access it with the class name where the enum in exists, for example ModelVehicle.Car?

```
Vehicle *hi = Car;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Objective-C, enums aren't a part of a class, so you reference them directly by name.

Comment: Aaa oke, but is it possible to use it as part of a class? Or is this the way is should?

Comment: @iMuller: You can certainly use it inside of a class, but it's never referenced as though it's a part of the class (the way you might in a language like Java).

Comment: This is a C++ 11 feature that must not be in Object C yet.

Answer (score 0):

The enum bit here isn't part of the objective c class. It's just a declaration of a c-enum in the same header as your objective c class